# What is the libraries in VB.net can submit in web page (PHP)?

Tags: php, vb.net, html

I am looking for something like cURL in PHP for VB.net.
I want to make edits for website with app in vb.net without going to real site to edit it

Answer (score 0):

A quick google came up with [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)